# How to use Alarm Manager on Android 9 and Android 10?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I am creating a Reminder App that let the user to set reminders for certian time and date. I use Alarm Manager that work fine for devices < android 6 .. Alarm manager does not work for long time alarms on android 8 and above because my foreground service, foreground Notifications and alarms are killed by OS.

I use workManager but i am unable to set reminders for exact time using workManager. I see many reminder apps on play store that work fine on android 9 and 10.

I also used   return START_REDELIVER_INTENT in onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) it works when i unlock the screen and put the device on charging then the os resume my services and alarms.

Comment: Your post lacks enough information to investigate the problem.  In particular, it's hard to help with code issues without seeing the relevant parts of the code—a description of the code is usually not enough.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Although if I had to guess...you may want to take a look at https://dontkillmyapp.com/ and see if that explains your issues.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned on Android version > 6, the OS kills background tasks after a little while, using foreground services is one solution but i find it annoying to the user.

I have a similar task/to-do reminder app used and i resolved to using Workmanager to set notification and certain time intervals and one good feature you get out of this is if the device restarts or reboots your saved alarms are resumed when the device is back online.

Check this tutorial, it uses *setInitialDelay* method of **OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder** to schedule alarm at specific time:

[Android Schedule Daily Repeating/Reminder Alarm at Specific Time With WorkManager](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-schedule-daily-reminder-alarm-at-specific-time-with-workmanager/)

Comment: looks like a very simple and cool solution but this solution did not work for me on android 10 when screen is locked ..

Comment: The doWork method is  called when I unlock the device

Comment: The schedule work is paused until the device screen is unlocked.

Comment: I'm think if this case you have to use foreground service, since If the app needs to complete a  task without deferring even if the user leaves the app or turns off the screen, such as in the case of music/video playback or navigation, i believe this ill work for you, i don't consider it good UX but it's worth a try if it'll do the trick

Comment: Like combining what you did with WM with Foreground service when user creates and alarm/reminder.

Comment: I am also using Foreground service with foreground notification but still I am unable to solve this issue..